# bashscript for quick change i3 mod key

Tags: bash, scripting, i3

i am trying to write a bash script to quick change the $mod key of i3
i moved the "set $mod Mod4" to the end of my conf

```
#!/bin/bash

$1=key
$alt="alt"
$win="win"

sed '$d' /home/fabian/.config/i3/config

if [ "$key" = "$win" ]; then
    echo "set \$mod Mod4" >> /home/fabian/.config/i3/config
    echo
    echo "Changed successfully to win"
else
if [ "$key" = "$alt" ]; then
    echo "set \$mod Mod1" >> /home/fabian/.config/i3/config
    echo
    echo "Changed successfully to alt"
else
    echo "No Flag valid flag set, set alt or win"
fi
fi
```

two problems:
the sed command is not working even if i run with sudo

if i run the script with "changeMod.sh alt" it still goes into the win condition and echos "Changed successfully to win"

if it's possible i would like the script to insert old $mod+shift+r to reload the i3 conf

Do you know how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your `sed` is missing the `-i` flag which would allow it to edit the file in place, but your method is unsafe — if you ran the script without a valid command multiple times you’d remove a line from your config every time. You also have a lot of duplication of effort.

This should do the trick in a safer, more succinct fashion. Creates a backup copy of the config, but you could prevent this by removing `.backup` from the `sed` line (subject to the available features of your `sed`).

```
#!/bin/bash

conf="/home/fabian/.config/i3/config"

case "${1}" in
  (alt) key=Mod1 ;;
  (win) key=Mod4 ;;
  (*)   printf "Invalid key: %s\n" "${1}" ; exit 1 ;;
esac

sed -i.backup 's/^\(set $mod\) .*/\1 '"${key}/" "${conf}" || exit

printf "Changed successfully to %s/%s\n" "${1}" "${key}"
```

Comment: great solution! do you also know if it's possible to insert a shortcut?

Comment: i found that it is possible to use xdotool for inserting shortcuts but i don't know how to check the current $mod key. 

I would need to find out the current mod key which is the last word of my i3 config file is that possible with sed?

Comment: `sed` is not the best tool for checking a current setting, I would probably use `awk` — but that’s a different question, so ask a new question.